# Is it possible to vectorize an agent-based model?

Tags: python, optimization, vectorization, agent-based-modeling

I have implemented my own agent-based model (ABM) in Python, using Python objects. Specifically, this is a model of Virus objects and Host objects, where Virus objects live in Host objects (stored in a list), can exchange genes with other Virus objects, and can be transmitted to another Host object when Host objects come in contact.

The OOP way makes it flexible and easy to program, but I'd be hard pressed to speed it up without, say, using PyPy or numba, or moving some of the code to Cython. Speed-ups are always good, so I won't go into why I'd want to do that here.

My question here is more fundamental, though. Is it possible to vectorize such models? Or does the hierarchical and interdependent nature of such a model make it logically impossible to implement using vectors and matrices?

Answer (score 1):

It's been a few days without any response, so I will see if I can get a debate going. I'm not familiar enough with Python to give a definite answer. But it likely depends on the details of the interactions (between agents, or between the agents and their enviroments) that you are trying to code. If it is acceptable to do something like:

> 1/ calculate the behaviour of each agent based on its current circumstances and store in a 'next timestep' variable
>
> 2/ update the variables to their 'next timestep' values

then there shouldn't be any problem in principle. But this is exactly why ABM builders often use either a specialised ABM language (such as NetLogo) or an OOP language. You might have a look at how [Repast Py](http://repast.sourceforge.net/repast_3/repastpy/) deals with these issues.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar question too. I use python OPP language to simulate a agent-based model in ecology (also call individual-based model). I simulate the interaction between individuals of each species in a biological community and each individuals compete for avalibale resource undergoning birth, reproducing, mutation, deadth and dispersal processes. I am also looking for a way to speed it up.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32628799)